# How to fll column values based on other columns in python

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I have a Dataset which looks like this:

```
ID      Date          A           B             
1       1-Nov         10          5            
1       2-Nov                     7
2       1-Nov         11          8 
2       2-Nov                     10
```

where we have some blank values in the column A, so in output wherever A is present output will be filled by those values, if A is not present it will be filled by B, so output will look like:

```
ID      Date          A           B           Output  
1       1-Nov         10          5             10
1       2-Nov                     7             7
2       1-Nov         11          8             11
2       2-Nov                     10            10
```

can anyone please help me on this:

Answer (score 1):

Use [`numpy.where`](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.where.html):

```
import numpy as np

df["Output"] = np.where(df["A"].isnull(), df["B"], df["A"])
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use a comparison to accomplish this:

```
df["Output"] = df.apply(lambda x: x['A'] if x['A']>0 else x['B'], axis=1)
```

Answer (score 0):

You can actually use `fillna()`. More concretely, I would use:

`df[New_Var] = df[A].fillna(df[B])`

In this case, if column A has a value, the new column will use the value from column A. If column A has missing values, values of column B will be used instead. Oh, and if your dataframe has blanks, and not missing, one additional step will be required to replace the blanks from the respective columns to missing instead.